# Wordpress brute attack , how to fix

Tags: wordpress

i have bin reading about this brute attack on wordpress site ( for example here http://blog.cloudflare.com/patching-the-internet-fixing-the-wordpress-br ) i have bin google-ing it for a while but there are still some questions left to answer.

- My wordpress site wont allow me to access wp-admin but redirects me to a error page, does that meen my site has bin hacked ?
- What to i need to today to be able to access my wp-admin site

Best , john

Comment: What error message is it displaying? Odds are your .htaccess file has been altered, which is what's redirecting you. It's not necessarily a sign you have been compromised; some hosts are adding this in as a heavy-handed precautionary measure. Check your .htaccess file and see what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Cpanel logs, and confirm whether your blog has been compromised or not. If it is changes related issue undo all the changes which you have done, you may also try to recover by deleting the themes directory in Cpanel. BEFORE THAT TAKE BACKUP OF YOUR DB IN CPANEL.

Answer (score 0):

just check it out wheher your cpanel has Wp_admin page or not. if it is not there your website has been compromised. in this case if u have back up of ur whole site . just upload your wp_admin page on ur server.